# [Syntax Help]What is "variable : () => " meaning in Typescript or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax

I was reading a source code about next-firebase-auth.

I am confused about the **following code syntax**

```
export const useAuthUser: () => AuthUserContext

export const verifyIdToken: (token: string) => Promise<AuthUser>
```

The right side look like an arrow function. The left side is declaring varibles. Intuitively, I am thinking is the same as the following:

```
export const useAuthUser = () => AuthUserContext
```

However, it doesn't. I did some test on Chrome console. Here is the code

```
adder : () => (a + b)
```

When I hit enter, it shows

```
() => (a+b)
```

But If I type adder, it shows

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: adder is not defined
```

I looked other posts here. It seems like the colon (:)  is related to **type annotation**. So does it mean the right side is a type or interface? But how is an arrow function type or interface? It does not make sense.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "*So does it mean the right side is a type or interface?*" yes. "*But how is an arrow function type or interface?*" why wouldn't it be? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html

Comment: My bad, I should have known **it is the type of a function**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff after the colon is the type. As a type, `() => AuthUserContext` means a function that doesn't require any arguments, and which returns an `AuthUserContext`. `(token: string) => Promise<AuthUser>` Means a function that requires a single argument which is a string, and then returns a Promise that will resolve to an `AuthUser`

The lines of code you showed seem incomplete. Typically, a const will immediately followed by an assignment, as in:

```
export const useAuthUser: () => AuthUserContext = () => {
  // some code which returns an AuthUserContext
}
```

> I did some test on Chrome console.

The console only supports javascript, not typescript

Comment: 1. Thanks for your detailed answer. Now I understand the code. Additional question, since Chrome console does not support the typescript, how Chrome resolve the code:
```ts
const adder : () => (a + b)
```

2. For the source code: here is the link:  https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth/blob/main/src/index.js

Comment: @YihanDuan "*how Chrome resolve the code: `ts const adder : () => (a + b)`*" it doesn't: [it throws a syntax error](https://i.imgur.com/V9T9cCc.png)

Comment: @VLAZ here is the my sreenshot. 
https://photos.app.goo.gl/SZHDjLL7N6Bganw89

Comment: @VLAZ If you cannot see the pic, you can try only type. It automatically returns the right part.
```adder : () => (a + b)```

Comment: @YihanDuan the code `adder : () => (a + b)` is *different* from the code `ts const adder : () => (a + b)`. You asked about the second one. The first one "works" because `adder` is [a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). It's still nothing at all like TS. It just means that the function `() => (a + b)` was created. It's not at type.